# Form does not get recognised

Tags: php, html

My form doesn't get recognised. Do you know why? I've checked everything, I just can not find the mistake. My PHP is supposed to take the info from the form and echo it out. PHP says 'Undefined array key "Dezi".'

```
<form action="DzBR.php" method="post">
    <input class="Dezi" name="Dezi" type="number">
</form>

<form action="DzBR.php" method="post">
    <button name="rechnen" class="rechnen">Rechnen</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your button in a different form from your data. When you click it only the button data is submitted. The numeric field is ignored.

Place both elements in a single form:

```
<form action="DzBR.php" method="post">
    <input class="Dezi" name="Dezi" type="number">
    <button name="rechnen" class="rechnen">Rechnen</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! :)